# Connecting a kitchen weighing scale to an AC/DC adapter

Tags: batteries, dc

I have a kitchen weighing scale that uses a lithium 3volts cr2032 coin cell to power it. I also have an AC/DC power adapter that can be set to 3volts output. Would it be safe to connect the weighing scale to the adapter directly? What are the possible implications of this action? I will appreciate your opinions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the voltage stable? if it has spikes over 3.5V, it may damage the scale, meant to be used with very stable and spike-free 3.3 V cells. Many AC/DC adaptors have significant spikes when used with very light loads (and the scale is a VERY light load).

Also, why do you do that? a wall socket is quite valuable in the kitchen, and a CR2032 cell should last months on a kitchen scale anyway. It's not a shaver which needs significant power...

Moreover, the AC/DC adapter will draw continuously some power even when the scale is off. You lose a wall socket and you waste energy!

Comment: I actually asked that because i have a scale that seems to be 'swallowing up' the cell power in less than a few hour every time i replace the cell. That's why I was curious for an alternative. Thanks for the great answer though . :-)

Comment: If the adapter is heavy, with maximum current about 700-1200 mA and has a slider with the selection of the voltage, it could be a transformer+linear regulator, not a DC/DC adapter. In that case it should be suitable for your scale when set to 3V. Like this one (be careful with polarity!) http://www.parts-express.com/Data/Default/Images/Catalog/Original/120-194_HR_0.jpg

Comment: @AstroguyPasa If your "3V" wall wart does produce say 3.0 +- 0.2 V at no load (I doubt it), then no problem. However, if your scale is consuming batteries at that rate, something is wrong with it in the first place.

Comment: @OlafM, it looks a bit similar to that one. The maximum current output is 500mA. it also has a knob to change the polarity which confused me a little.

Comment: @winny. I will need to measure the output consistency to see if it really fluctuates.

Comment: @AstroguyPasa it should be ok. Do you have a multimeter? set the AC/DC to 3V and the multimeter to AC mode with the lowest setting (AC has usually 20V, 250V, 750V setting or similar). Measure the output of the adapter, without devices connected to it. The value gives you an approximation of the max fluctuations your scale with experience. If below 0.2V, you can use it. The tester will also help you (in DC mode) to get the polarity correct for your scale.

Comment: @AstroguyPasa It won't flutuate, just give higher voltage at no load and your scale is as close to no load it makes no difference what the wall wart adapter is concerned. If you have a multimeter and do rig this up, I would spend the time to measure the current consumption of your scale. If it drains the batteries in hours, it will be in mA scale and unless you have a very low end multimeter, you should be able to measure it.